# Why can't I access a namespace added through NuGet?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, using, mathnet-numerics

Because I want to use matrices in my program, I added the Math.NET library through NuGet in Visual Studio 2015. However, although I can see the library files in the Project References folder, VS doesn't seem to recognize any of the references to it. Autocomplete won't suggest MathNet when writing the using-command, and it won't recognize any of the classes from that namespace either, of course. Are there any more steps I'm missing?

Comment: Check references - whether Meth.NET reference was successfully added and that there is no yellow exclamation mark

Comment: do you see it in your references?

Comment: Did you install the package in the correct project?  maybe you had a different project selected when you installed the nuget package

Comment: And just to make sure this is clear - although certain conventions *tend* to be followed, NuGet package names, assembly names and the namespace(s) contained within any particular assembly are three orthogonal concepts. You *don't* add a namespace through NuGet, you add a package.

Comment: As far as I can tell, everything appears to be in order - it's in the right project, and I can't see any warnings. Here's a screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/DGKW7Vd.png)

Comment: @Leo-MSFT I realized that "using" apparently doesn't include child namespaces, so after using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra instead the IDE did recognize the new object types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I still can't say why autocomplete didn't suggest the namespace (even though after attempting to build it it did end up showing in the suggestions), I can confirm that the source of my problem was that matrices and vectors need to be imported with MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra, not MathNet.Numerics.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I access a namespace added through NuGet?

Whether there is a error when you add the using command:`using MathNet.Numerics;`?

Not sure why autocomplete won't suggest MathNet when you write the using-command, it works fine on my machine, I will write detail steps here so that you can check the difference, then find some help.

Detail Steps:

1. Create a new blank c# class library project.
2. Add the package `MathNet.Numerics` to the project by NuGet.
3. Open a .cs file, add `using MathNet.Numerics` and instantiate a class "**Permutation**" (Most classes are static class).

[image]

Comment: After noticing that the Permutation class works fine, I realized that the IDE recognizes the Vector- and Matrix-classes if I wrote using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra. Doesn't the compiler include all the subfolder when importing a library?

Comment: @KönigNickerchen, So you can access a namespace added through NuGet now? If above answer resolve your question, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. If not, let me know your question. Thanks.